# Insert a Formula in a range which includes variant

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to write a code to insert below formula in the range("c6:c205").
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C6;Pricelist!A5:F21997;2;FALSE);" ")

Could you please help me to correct the following code.
Thank you in advance.

```
For i = 6 To 205
Dim myFormula As String        
        myFormula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C"
        myFormula = myFormula & i
        myFormula = myFormula & ";Pricelist!A5:F21997;2;FALSE);"
        myFormula = myFormula & " "" "
        myFormula = myFormula & ")"
        
        
        Range("E" & i).Formula = myFormula
        
 Next
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do it in one without a loop, it will automatically adjust.

`range("e6:e205").formula="=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C6,Pricelist!$A$5:$F$21997,2,FALSE),"" "")`

In VBA you don't use local settings such as ;

And you need to double-up the quotes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: could you please guide me how I can put the following formula in the cell as well?
=SUMIFS(G6:GG;G6:GG;"<>#VALUE!"; G6:GG; "<>#N/A")
currently I am using the following and it works, but not exactly what I want
ActiveSheet.Range("G" & LastrowAS).Formula = "=SUM(G3 :GG)"
when I replace sumif with sum formula in the code, i receive an error

Comment: Could you start a new question please. G3:GG is not a valid reference as you need a row number too.

Answer (score 0):

You need not have so many lines of code to get this. Try:

Sub AddFormula()

```
Dim myFormula As String
myFormula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C6,pricelist!A5:F21997,2,FALSE),"""")"

For i = 6 To 10
    Range("E" & i).Formula = myFormula
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use commas and fix some double-quotes:

```
Sub ksdjfhs()
    dq = Chr(34)
    For i = 6 To 205
        Dim myFormula As String
        myFormula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C"
        myFormula = myFormula & i
        myFormula = myFormula & ",Pricelist!A5:F21997,2,FALSE),"
        myFormula = myFormula & dq & dq
        myFormula = myFormula & ")"
            
        Range("E" & i).Formula = myFormula
 Next
End Sub
```